# Read an office 365 mailbox using Exchange web services

Tags: c#, office365, exchangewebservices, office365api

I am using this below code but unable to read my office 365 Inbox emails from C# code. Once I get this working then later I would need to read emails from shared mailbox.

I’d really appreciate if someone could please help me in fixing this issue or guide me what am I missing here ?

If I use Url as Office365 one then getting this error: "The request failed. The remote server returned an error 401. Unauthorized "

If I use Url as casx16 one (found this in company's Q/A portal) then getting this error: " No mailbox with such GUID "

```
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

public static void ReadMyMailbox_2()

        {

ExchangeService exchangeService = new ExchangeService();

exchangeService.Credentials = new WebCredentials("ajain", "password ", "MS");    ///  ajain is my MSID

// exchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl("a_jain@xyz.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

exchangeService.Url = new Uri("https://casx16.xyz.com/ews/exchange.asmx");

// exchangeService.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

 

FolderId mailbox = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "a_jain@xyz.com");

ItemView itemView = new ItemView(10);

 

FindItemsResults<Item> result = exchangeService.FindItems(mailbox, itemView);

foreach (var msg in result)

{

EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(exchangeService, msg.Id);

                  Console.WriteLine(message.Subject);

}

        }
```

Comment: I would suggest testing it with the EWSEditor https://github.com/dseph/EwsEditor/releases this gives the option of using both basic or oAuth against Office365 you should be using the latter as basic auth is being depreciated. But this will tell if you can access your mailbox. Also if you have an Office365 mailbox why not just use the Graph API you can test that using the Graph Explorer https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: Thats something new.. sure will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're setting up the ExchangeService object correctly. A couple things to try:

1. Try passing the full email (a_jain@xyz.com) to WebCredentials
2. Make sure your the domain you're passing to WebCredentials is correct
3. Try the WebCredentials constructor that only takes username and password.

Note: I don't think autodiscover will work with O365

Comment: sure will try. Lets see.

Comment: ok.. tried all 3 .. same errors with urls mentioned in question.